# Difference between Verdad and Cierto

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

What's the difference between `cierto` and `verdad`? I know that they both mean "Correct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cierto` is an adjective and one of its definitions according to the [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) is *"Known as true,..."*; so its meaning is *right* or *correct*.

`Verdad` is a noun and stands as *truth*.

In day to day conversations, they are exchangeable as when you say "es verdad" you are actually telling "it is true".